# Отправить post запрос html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, post, api

Отправить запрос методом `POST` на сторонний сайт, как это сделать правильно, в форме будет 2-3 поля для заполнения, нужно написать скрипт отправления 
поля именуются:

- fio
- phone
- additional11

```js
var num_params = document.getElementById('nums').value  //кол-во строчек для параметров запроса
 var formZ = document.getElementById('post_me');  //отправляемая форма
 formZ.action = document.getElementById('url').value;  //форма для url адреса
 var meth = document.forms[0].method;
 formZ.method = meth.options[meth.selectedIndex].value;  //проверяем какой метод выбран post или get
 var enctype = document.forms[0].enctype;
 formZ.enctype = enctype.options[enctype.selectedIndex].value;  //проверяем какой выбран метод кодирования формы

 for (i=1; i<=num_params; i++) {  //если введено имя запроса, назначаем его форме со значением запроса
  var namez=document.getElementById('nam_' + i); 
  var valz=document.getElementById('val_' + i);
  if(namez.value!=''){
   valz.name=namez.value;
  }else{
   break;
  }
    }
 formZ.submit();
 if(document.forms[0].interval.value > 0){
  interval=setInterval(function(){formZ.submit()}, document.forms[0].interval.value * 1000);
 }
}

function set_target(sel){
 var target=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
 target=(target=='frame') ? Math.random() : target;
 document.getElementById('post_me').target=target;
}

function NewRow(ob) {//для добавления новых строк параметров запроса
 var num = ob.id;
 var num  = num.substr(num.lastIndexOf("_")+1);
 num++;
        var nums=document.alternate.nums.value;
 if(nums==num)
 {
  num++;
  var tbl = document.getElementById("t");
  var cnt = tbl.rows.length;
  var oRow = tbl.insertRow(cnt);
  var oCell = oRow.insertCell(0);
  oCell.innerHTML = '\n<input type="text" id="nam_'+num+'" value="" size="30">\n';
  var oCell = oRow.insertCell(1);
  oCell.innerHTML = '\n<input type="text" id="val_'+num+'" onChange="NewRow(this)" value="" size="50">\n';
  document.alternate.nums.value = num;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <form hidden name="alternate">
  
  <input hidden type="text" id="url" value="ссылка API"> <!-- задаем свою ссылку куда отправлять запрос -->
  <select name="method">
   <option value="POST">POST</option>
  </select>
    
        <select hidden name="enctype">
          <option value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">application/x-www-form-urlencoded</option>
        </select>
        
  <select hidden onchange="set_target(this)">
   <option value="_self">В этом окне</option>
  </select>
  <input hidden value="-1" id="interval" name="interval"> 

  <input type="hidden" id="nums" value="3">
 </form>
</div>

<div style="float: left;">
 <form id="post_me" name="post_me" target="_blank">
  
    <input type="text" name="fio" id="fio" value="">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
                <input type="text" name="additional11" id="additional11" value="">
   
   
  <input type="button" onclick="sendit()" value="Оформить заказ">
  
 </form>
</div>
```

```
var valz=document.getElementById('val_' + i);
if(namez.value!=''){
valz.name=namez.value;
}else{
break;
}
}
formZ.submit();
if(document.forms[0].interval.value > 0){
    interval=setInterval(function(){formZ.submit()}, 
document.forms[0].interval.value * 1000);
}
}

function set_target(sel){
var target=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
target=(target=='frame') ? Math.random() : target;
document.getElementById('post_me').target=target;
}

function NewRow(ob) { //для добавления новых строк параметров запроса
var num = ob.id;
var num  = num.substr(num.lastIndexOf("_")+1);
num++;
    var nums=document.alternate.nums.value;
if(nums==num)
{
num++;
var tbl = document.getElementById("t");
var cnt = tbl.rows.length;
var oRow = tbl.insertRow(cnt);
var oCell = oRow.insertCell(0);
oCell.innerHTML = '\n<input type="text" id="nam_'+num+'" value="" 
size="30">\n';
var oCell = oRow.insertCell(1);
oCell.innerHTML = '\n<input type="text" id="val_'+num+'" 
onChange="NewRow(this)" value="" size="50">\n';
document.alternate.nums.value = num;
}
}
```

Comment: А что вы пробовали сделать? В чем у вас конкретно возникают проблемы? Есть ли у вам пример кода, который вы делали?

Comment: я пробовал сделать через код, который я вытащил из онлайн отправки пост запроса, даже получилось отправить свою форму, но там передавались не все поля моей формы, т.к я оставил скрипт и форму такой какой она была на онлайн обработчике, но просто спрятал поля, которые мне не нужны, выглядело все хорошо, но код ужасный, я думаю)

Comment: Приложите код, и укажите, что именно вы видите в нем "ужасного", желательно чтобы был и html и js, чтобы было понятнее с этим разбираться. Для внесения изменений в ваш вопрос нажмите кнопку "править".

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам простой пример отправки данных с формы на сторонний сайт методом `POST`:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#example_form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // запретим стандартное поведения отправки данных
  var data = $(this).serializeArray(); // получаем данные с формы

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://new-site.ru/example_script', // адрес скрипта который примит данные
    type: 'POST', // метод передачи
    dataType: 'JSON', // !если требуется! получить ответ как массив данных используем формат JSON
    data: data // передаем массив данных
  }).done(function(res) {
    alert('Данные успешно переданы!');
    console.log(res);
    $('#example_form').trigger('reset'); // сбрасываем данные формы
  }).fail(function(err) {
    alert('Ошибка передачи запроса.');
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

```css
#example_form input,
#example_form textarea,
#example_form button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="example_form">
  <input type="text" name="fio" placeholder="Ф.И.О." />
  <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона" />
  <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="additional" placeholder="Дополнительная информация"></textarea>

  <button type="submit">Отправить данные</button>
</form>
```